# Why does not the block closing work when the button is pressed again?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a menu and the behavior for clicks in different places, but only the function that opens the menu when you press the button works. Closing the same menu when clicking on the same button does not work. I don't know, maybe I wrote the wrong condition for closing. I can not understand. Where am I wrong?

```js
function hideMenu(menuId) {
  if ($(menuId).is(":visible")) {
    $(menuId).hide();
  } else {
    $(".hiddenMenu:visible").hide();
    $(menuId).show('800');
  }
  
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var div = $(menuId);
    if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      div.hide();
    }
  });

  console.log(menuId);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #040921;
}

.container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #263154;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container nav ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#submenuId1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  background: orange;
  display: none;
}

#submenuId2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a onclick="hideMenu('#submenuId1')">Link</a></li>
      <li><a onclick="hideMenu('#submenuId2')">Link</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="submenuId1" class="hiddenMenu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>subMenuItem1</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="submenuId2" class="hiddenMenu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>subMenuItem1</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: In your else statement you are hiding it and then 800ms showing it again.

Comment: @tshimkus But the `else` only runs if the specified DIV isn't already visible.

Comment: You shouldn't add the `$(document).mouseup()` handler every time you click on a menu. You end up with lots of duplicate handlers.

Answer (score 0):

`$(menuId).is(":visible")` is never returning `true`. The next time you click on the link, the `$(document).mouseup()` handler runs *before* the `onclick` handler runs. Since you're not clicking on the DIV, it hides the DIV. Then the `onclick` handler runs, it sees that the DIV is hidden, so it shows it again.

When detecting a click outside the DIV, you also need to exclude clicks on the menu titles.

You shouldn't add `mouseup` handler every time you call `hideMenu()`, as you create multiple handlers that all run the next time you click. Declare that event handler just once, and have it simply close the `:visible` menu.

```js
function hideMenu(menuId) {
  if ($(menuId).is(":visible")) {
    $(menuId).hide();
  } else {
    $(".hiddenMenu:visible").hide();
    $(menuId).show('800');
  }

  console.log(menuId);
}

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var div = $(".hiddenMenu:visible");
  if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0 && !$(e.target).hasClass("menutitle")) {
    div.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #040921;
}

.container {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #263154;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container nav ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#submenuId1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  background: orange;
  display: none;
}

#submenuId2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menutitle" onclick="hideMenu('#submenuId1')">Link</a></li>
      <li><a class="menutitle" onclick="hideMenu('#submenuId2')">Link</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="submenuId1" class="hiddenMenu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>subMenuItem1</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="submenuId2" class="hiddenMenu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>subMenuItem1</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: When several page reloads, this method again stops working.

Comment: Nothing is saved automatically across reloads. If you want to do that, you need to add code to do it using `localStorage`.

Comment: Hmm ... Thank you. Are there any other methods for closing a block when clicking outside it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element